# "A breakpoint instruction (__debugbreak() statement or a similar call) was executed in Main.exe", but there is no error?

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime-error, heap-memory, visual-studio-2022

I have an infinite loop that breaks if user exits out of the main window. I have the following code running in the loop:

```
unsigned int* renderableShapeIndices = new unsigned int[aNumberCreatedAtRuntime];
// Do something
delete[] renderableShapeIndices;
```

Then the following happens a couple of loop iterations and cease to happen after the first iteration:

```
1st breakpoint:
A breakpoint instruction (__debugbreak() statement or a similar call) was executed in Main.exe.

2nd breakpoint:
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8C3B8C729 (ntdll.dll) in InTimeEngine2D.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x00007FF8C3BF7780).
```

Has anyone else gone through similar issues? I have no idea what is going on.

Another interesting factor about this is that it only happens in debug mode. It does not happen in release mode.

Comment: The program corrupted the heap, probably by running off the end of an array somewhere, perhaps in `// Do something`. The problem with heap corruption is it may not be immediately detectable, so you'll need to work backwards from where it was detected to see what the cause is. Tools like AddressSanitizer may help you catch it as it happens. The heap is most likely still corrupted in release mod, but the debug heap has extra checks to help you not ship something with corruption or undefined behavior.

Comment: You are right about the heap memory corruption. One of the times I ran I got a similar error, but I did not include it in the main post because I only got that message once. But it was something along those lines. Thank you for your response. I will try to find the error now that I have this lead. Also, why would the error happen on deletion though and not on "// Do something"? I also get other messages when I step over in debug mode: "ucrtbased.pdb, delete_array.cpp and delete_scalar.cpp not found"

Comment: Also, is it possible to get this error because somewhere else in my program I write to memory and it ends up writing to the memory in renderableShapeIndices and consequently cause this error?

Comment: The debugger tries to load the source code for where it breaks. You most likely do not have the CRT code installed, it's optional, and even if you do sometimes the debugger won't find it without help. The consistency checks for the heap only happen when an operation that triggers them is called, like `new` or `delete`. That's why you need to work backwards because the problem happened before it was detected.

Comment: You are right about everything. Thank you so much. I appreciate your response. In `// Do something` I was creating an array of size 27, then edited it be size 18, but forgot to edit the code to write up to element 18 (index 17). So I was indeed writing to more than what I allocated initially? Apparently, in my understanding, ends up writing to other places of the code and messes them up.

Comment: For me, the problem was assigning 0 array size (dynamically) and once another time the problem was wrong indexing inside GPU kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the problem is in the comment section of the question.

Apparently, if one attempts to write to an array outside of its bounds, it will, but it ends up overwriting data of other places in the code, causing bugs in other parts of the program, even if these two parts of the program are unrelated. In my case, they were completely unrelated.

Comment: C++ is not my first language.

Comment: Well I don't know your previous experience but not all languages are like C and C++ in this regard. Java, for instance, has well defined behaviour even on out of bounds accesses. So maybe you were misled by your previous experience.

Comment: In C++ pretty much any 'breaking of the rules' results in *undefined behaviour*, which allows compilers to generate fast but brittle code.